# how to shift focus on another element in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to finish a homework assignment that has me doing this:

1) Create a new html form.

Objects:

Email Address Text Box (active)

Phone Number Text Box (disabled)

Submit Button (disabled)

2) Instruct the user to enter email address.

- Validate the emaill address has an @ and a . in the email address when the user leaves the text box.

Success

```
1) enable Phone Number Text Box
2) focus is given to the phone number text box
```

Failure

```
1) use a warning message that the field value  is invalid and how to correctly enter the value.
2) focus returns to the email address text box.
```

- Validate the phone number is 10 digits but no special characters when the user leaves the text box.

Success

```
1) reformat the phone number to use dashes (e.g. 123-321-4545).
2) focus is given to the submit button 
3) enable the submit button
```

Failure

```
1) use a warning message that the field value is invalid and how to correctly enter the value.
2) focus returns to the phone number text box.
```

- Submit button responds with a success message that all fields validate.

This is what I have so far. I just cant figure out how to get the focus to shift to the phone number or the submit button if the first run is a success

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
<script type="text/javascript">

function checkForm(form)
{
// validation fails if the input is blank
if(form.inputfield.value == "") {
alert("Error: Input is empty!");
form.inputfield.focus();
return false;
}

// regular expression to match only alphanumeric characters and spaces
var re = /^[\w ]+$/;

// validation fails if the input doesn't match our regular expression
if(!re.test(form.inputfield.value)) {
alert("Error: Input contains invalid characters!");
form.inputfield.focus();
return false;
}

// validation was successful
return true;
}
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("myText").focus();
};

</script>
</header>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
E-mail:    <input type="email" name="email" id="myText" required 
placeholder="Enter a valid email address">
<label for="phonenum">Phone Number (format: xxx-xxx-xxxx):</label>
<input type="tel" placeholder="Enter a valid phone number" pattern="^\d{3}-
\d{3}-\d{4}$" disabled required>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

(can anyone help me before the day is up?)

Comment: We aren't here to do your homework.

Comment: You are calling `focus()` in some places, is it not working? Do you have any errors?

Comment: Also, **where** and **how** do you call `checkForm()`? I don't think `inputfield` exists in your document.

Comment: I agree we aren't here to do people's homework, but a lot of questions on here are people's homework. The OP shouldn't be penalized for explicitly mentioning what this is for. Atleast they are showing their attempt and what exactly they're stuck on.

Comment: Is "how do I shift focus?" your actual question? If so, you seem to already know that `focus()` does that, and even if you didn't the answer can be easily found via Google and is a duplicate on this site. However, it seems the actual issue is you don't understand how to use it.